# Correct way to remove(purge) all keychain data for an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I stored some information in the keychain, and there is a case that I need to remove all of the items, instead of doing `[keychain removeObjectForKey:theKey]` for all the keys, can I do:

```
NSDictionary *spec = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecClass,
                      [self serviceName], kSecAttrService, nil];

return !SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)spec);
```

instead?

I tried it and it worked, just not sure if I am doing the correct thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in my app I'm using this line to clear my keychain :

```
[[[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"my_key" accessGroup:nil] resetKeychainItem]
```

Comment: What is that identifier? Is it the kSecAttrService?

Comment: You can choose whatever identifier you'd like, in case you need to have multiple KeychainItem handled in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are doing is correct, in fact, you can avoid the kSecAttrService parameter in your query if you want. On the other hand, the SecItemDelete returns a OSStatus value which you can check for more detailed information about the transaction.

```
    NSDictionary *spec = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecClass, nil];

    OSStatus status = SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)spec);
    if (status == errSecSuccess)
       return YES;

    return NO;
```

[Here are the codes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898-CH5g-CJBEABHG) and meanings for the possible status values